# ¿Cómo "customizar" el formulario para PasswordChangeView en django allauth?

Tags: django

estoy usando [Django Allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) y tengo éstas líneas en mi proyecto

```
from allauth.account.views import PasswordChangeView  as PasswordChangeParentView

class PasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeParentView):
    """
    overwrite get_success_url to allow to redirect
    the user to a custom place after changing his password
    """

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('projects:index')
```

actualmente me pide la contraseña antigua y una nueva y la confirmación de la nueva contraseña.

lo que yo quiero es no pedir la contraseña anterior para poder cambiar la contraseña.

Answer (score 0):

No lo he probado pero supongo que deberás crear un form que herede de [ChangePasswordForm](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/519f1f2026691a98e76f5fc3d998d235e53cfe57/allauth/account/forms.py#L454) y anular la propiedad `oldpassword` y el metodo `clean_oldpassword`

En tu `view.py` añadir `form_class` al form que has creado.

Creo que con eso o poco mas te deberá de funcionar